# adding checked attribute in radio button when checked by ternary operator

Tags: jquery, radio-button

here is the statement

```
content += '<tr>
            <td>Tier 
            <input type="radio" name="'qid+'tier'+(i+1)+'" "' +((des4=="1")? "checked" : "") +'" value=1 >1
            <input type="radio" name="'qid+'tier'+(i+1)+'" "' +((des4=="2")? "checked" : "") +'" value=2 >2
            <input type="radio" name="'qid+'tier'+(i+1)+'" "' +((des4=="3")? "checked" : "") +'" value=3 >3
            <input type="radio" name="'qid+'tier'+(i+1)+'" "' +((des4=="4")? "checked" : "") +'" value=4 >4<td></tr>';
```

this will give output some thing like this

```
<input type="radio" "checked" name="q12tier1" value="2">
```

and not

```
<input type="radio" checked name="q12tier1" value="2">
```

which will enable the radio button, tried single quote, double quote, but not working, need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove the double quotes around the ternary. You're also missing a `+` before `qid`. Try this:

```
content += '<tr>
        <td>Tier 
        <input type="radio" name="'+qid+'tier'+(i+1)+'" ' +((des4=="1")? 'checked="checked"': "") +' value=1 >1
        <input type="radio" name="'+qid+'tier'+(i+1)+'" ' +((des4=="2")? 'checked="checked"' : "") +' value=2 >2
        <input type="radio" name="'+qid+'tier'+(i+1)+'" ' +((des4=="3")? 'checked="checked"' : "") +' value=3 >3
        <input type="radio" name="'+qid+'tier'+(i+1)+'" ' +((des4=="4")? 'checked="checked"' : "") +' value=4 >4<td></tr>';
```

Also note that it would be better to create the HTML in a loop to stop the duplicate code:

```
var content = '';
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    content += '<input type="radio" name="' + qid + 'tier' + i +'" ' + (des4 == i ? 'checked="checked"' : "") + ' value="' + i + '">' + i
}
content = '<tr><td>Tier' + content + '</td></tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove double quotes before and after id consitions, Try:

```
content += '<tr>
            <td>Tier 
            <input type="radio" name="'qid+'tier'+(i+1)+'" ' +((des4=="1")? "checked" : "") +' value=1 >1
            <input type="radio" name="'qid+'tier'+(i+1)+'" ' +((des4=="2")? "checked" : "") +' value=2 >2
            <input type="radio" name="'qid+'tier'+(i+1)+'" ' +((des4=="3")? "checked" : "") +' value=3 >3
            <input type="radio" name="'qid+'tier'+(i+1)+'" ' +((des4=="4")? "checked" : "") +' value=4 >4<td></tr>';
```